# Extract email address from string: invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: vba, outlook

The idea is to scan incoming emails for a particular subject line, extract and reply to the email address from the first line of the email.

The issue lies in the emailC line, where it is telling me it is an invalid procedure call or argument.

```vb
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
                         
    Dim mymail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set mymail = ns.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)
                      
    Substr = Trim(mymail.Subject)
    If InStr(1, Substr, "TEST SUBJECT") > 0 Then
        sText = mymail.Body   
        vText = Split(sText, Chr(13), -1, vbTextCompare)
        'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
        emailC = Trim(Left(sText, InStr(sText, "<") - 1)) 'Split(vText(0), " ", -1, vbTextCompare)
        Resultstr = Trim(Mid(sText, InStr(sText, ">") + 1))
        senderstr = mymail.SenderEmailAddress
        
        Call SendReply(emailC, mymail.Subject, Resultstr, senderstr)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SendReply(Tostr, Subjectstr, Bodystr, senderstr)
    Dim mymail2 As Outlook.MailItem
    Set mymail2 = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
     
    nam = mymail2.Session.CurrentUser.Name

    With mymail2
        .To = senderstr
        .Subject = "RE: " & Subjectstr
        .ReplyRecipients.Add emailC
        .Body = Replace(Bodystr, Tostr, "", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)           
    End With

    mymail2.Send
     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the mail Body does not contain any '<' or '>'. In that case, the `Instr` will return `0`, and you end up with a command `left(sText, -1)` which will exacly throw the error you describe

For a starter, change your code

```
dim p as integer
p = InStr(sText, "<") 
if p = 0 then
    debug.Print "no '<' found, text = :" & sText
else
    emailC = Trim(Left(sText, p - 1)) 
    ....
```

After that you have to make up your mind what to do in such a case (and you should also the case that you find a '<' but no '>')

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `<` and `>` are in `sText` represented as `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally good practice to declare all your variables even if they're just Strings.

I would do this for all the String's you're using. I would also change your SendReply routine as follows:

Private Sub SendReply(ByVal Tostr as String, ByVal Subjectstr as String, ByVal Bodystr as String, ByVal senderstr as String)

From memory, if you don't do the above, the code doesn't know what data type the variables should be.